# EF5 Code First: IsLoaded and .AsNoTracking()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an EF5 Code First project that pulls from a mostly read-only database, so I'm using `.AsNoTracking()` with the vast majority of my queries to improve performance.

I'm curious, though: I have a number of navigation properties, and at times it would be useful to know if they've already been loaded, either following an `.Include()` on the source query, or due to the property being accessed (if configured for lazy loading).

Normally I could do:

```
context.Entry(myEntity).Reference(e => e.MyNavigationProperty).IsLoaded;
```

but naturally that won't work with untracked entities, since, well, they're untracked.  I have a feeling the answer is "no," but is there a way to determine if a navigation property has been loaded on an untracked entity (without resorting to anything messy like reflection on the dynamic proxy)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below is not going to work with entities loaded from db by accessing not-tracked entity. Although subsequent reference to that navigation property do not create db hit, the navigation property is not tracked by Entity Framework. I'm leaving this as an example of how not to do it ;)

How about using Local? So let say you have

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int MyEntityId { get; set;}
    public int MyNavigationPropertyID { get; set;}
    public MNP MyNavigationProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MNP
{
    public int MNPID { get; set;}
}
```

You can do that:

```
context.MyNavigationProperties.Local.Where(e => e.MNPID == MyNavigationProperty);
```

Local stores entities that are currently being tracked and not marked as deleted. I haven't tested that but it should work.

Comment: No dice -- since the entity is untracked, it (and its related entities) are not cached in the context.  `Local.Count` is always 0.

Comment: If NMP is loaded as tracked then you should be able to find it in local. If all your entities are loaded as untracked then I don't think you would be able to get this information from dbcontext as... they are not tracked. Let's wait for Slauma.

Comment: Yeah, getting the information from the context seems unlikely, but the information must be contained in the entity itself (since it would need to keep track of whether the value was already lazy-loaded, etc.).  I was hoping there was some obscure method somewhere that might provide access to that information. :)

Comment: I spent now hours on that and as far as I can see you won't be able to access that without operating directly on proxy where the entity (or rather its values) are stored. That means reflection. That information is definitively not stored in context as loading parent again will cause lazy-loading to hit the db again. Good luck!

Comment: Wow, sorry you went to all that trouble, but thanks for looking!  That's pretty much what I figured.